# How to use (Bootstrap + jQuery) and react-bootstrap on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

## Context

We have a "legacy" app that relies on Bootstrap 3 with jQuery and Symfony as the backend. But on the last page I built I used React for the page content.

So, while the "container" (the navigation bar, the header, etc.) is made using Bootstrap and jQuery, the content (a "sub app" for taking attendance) were made using React.

Everything went well. Then I noticed there were a "react-bootstrap" library so I replaced my "div + bootstrap classes" with react-bootstrap components.

## Problem

The first element that is loaded is a collapsible panel. There you can select some things that load another panel. As you may know, react-bootstrap doesn't need jQuery but uses its internal JS (great!). But the Bootstrap + jQuery of the container takes that panel into account when it (the container) is initializing and apply the jQuery "things" (event listeners and some HTML attributes I think) to my react-bootstrap panel.

So I ended up with a panel with double logic and things like the collapse button doesn't work well anymore because React closes the panel and then jQuery opens it.

The other panel that is loaded after pressing a button of the first one works well because it's generated after jQuery applies its "things".

## Possible solution

1. We have a "Pace" plugin that emits a "done" event when Bootstrap ended its initialization. If I execute ReactDom.render() after that event is emitted, everything works well (as expected), but it leaves an empty page until jQuery ends (least than 1 second but noticeable). Yes, I could use a loading screen. The container already has a loading screen that disappears as soon as the app script is loaded so I can't use it again because it would appear again and that's not good UX (I can not make it not disappear).
2. Instead of using the Panel component, I could use the classic "div + bootstrap classes" just for the Panel container that controls the toggle. The problem is that I would have to do that for every Bootstrap component that appears first (not only on this page but every other page).

## Maybe a hint?

Is there a way I can stop jQuery propagating to my React node? Take into account that, my app still uses CSS from the "container" (the bootstrap base, the bootstrap theme, etc)?

Comment: Would `<iframe>` work for the react section?

Comment: You can import react table CSS module into specific modules. In your case, don't import `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` into the index.js or whatever the your root js is.